# How to verify if AdjacencyGraph represents a DAG?

Tags: c#, graph, quicksort, directed-acyclic-graphs

Using QuickGraph library, I am holding an `AdjacencyGraph<TVertex,Edge<TVertex>>` of dircted graph.
I want to verify if the following graph represents a DAG. Is there are any algorithm on the library to do that?

What I was able to do was verify if the graph is cycle, but that's not enough to prove DAG. And seems like most of the library components algorithms work on undirected graphs

Answer (score 0):

If it is acyclic and the edges are directed, then it is a DAG.

I don't know the QuickGraph library, but if the question is whether all edges are also directed and the library does not tell you this directly, then you could ask each node for its child and parent nodes.

If a node appears as child and a parent for any node, then there must be either a cycle or the edge is undirected and thus maybe not considered in the cycle check like two inverse directed edges.

This would be more of a last resort though if there is no more reasonable way to figure this out.

Comment: Correct, I think acyclic with directed edges proves DAG. Any Ideas how to check the number of components?

Comment: Components are usually considered to be of undirected graphs. But perhaps what you are looking for are strongly connected components, which account for the directed edges. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strongly-connected-components/